# Straightening the boundary in concrete examples

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open and with $C^1$ boundary $\Gamma$.
For any given point $x_0 \in \Gamma$ we know there's a neighborhood where
$\Gamma$ is the graph of some $C^1$ function $\gamma : \mathbb{R}^{d - 1}
\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d, x' \longmapsto \gamma ( x') = x_d$. We can use
it to *straighten the boundary* with the local diffeomorphism

$$ T ( x', x_d - \gamma ( x')) = ( x', x_d - \gamma ( x')), $$

and its differential $D T$ has a nice $( d - 1) \times ( d - 1)$ identity
matrix as first block and a bottom row $\nabla T_d = ( - \nabla \gamma, 1)$
which is proportional to the vector $\vec{n}$ normal to $\Gamma$ at each
point, say $c ( x)  \vec{n} ( x) = \nabla T_d ( x)$, where $c ( x) = - \|
\nabla T_d ( x) \|$.

For my calculations in concrete examples with parametrized domains, etc., I
want $\nabla T_d$ to actually be the outward pointing normal: I need this $c (
x)$ to be $- 1$. If I try to impose the condition after constructing $T$, then
I have to integrate expressions which I'm just not capable of. I can try to
throw it at some symbolic integration software, but there has to be some other
way, right? In almost every book on PDEs it's stated that this $T$ may be
normalized so as to have the property I mention. But how?

Comment: I think the implicit function theorem could give you the answer.

Comment: With the implicit function theorem I can infer existence of $\gamma$
representing locally $\Gamma$ as the nullset of some $F ( x', x_N) = 0$ to
which the theorem applies. Then using the chain rule I see that
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} = - \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_d} 
   \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_i}, $$
and this allows me to write the normal vector using this function $F$, but I
don't see how I can use this to explictly normalize my transformation $T$ with
actual coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, I was being too optimistic. I don't think this is an easy problem: For curves the property you need is given by using the arc-length parametrization which I don't think has a higher dimensional analog. Could you give a reference where this statement is used?

Comment: It turned out it was easier than we both thought… As to the reference, I admit I can't give any without looking it up, but I've seen it stated often enough and thanks to Lukas Geyer we now know it's definitely true :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi(x')$ denotes the $d$-th component of the normal vector at $(x',\gamma(x'))$, then first of all it is immediate from the graph structure that $\phi(x') \ne 0$. Let $S(x',y_d) = (x',\phi(x')y_d)$, and write $\tilde{T} = S \circ T$. Then $\tilde{T}$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ diffeomorphism which straightens the boundary, and it is normalized, as can be checked easily with the chain rule:
$$
DS (x',y_d) = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{Id} & 0 \\ \hline
\nabla \phi(x') y_d & \phi(x')
\end{array}
\right]
$$
In particular
$$
DS (x',0) = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{Id} & 0 \\ \hline
0 & \phi (x')
\end{array}
\right]
$$
So on the boundary $\Gamma$ you get
$$
D\tilde{T}(x',\gamma(x')) = DS(x',0) DT(x',\gamma(x'))
=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm{Id} & 0 \\ \hline
-\phi(x')\nabla \gamma(x') & \phi (x')
\end{array}
\right]
$$
I.e., the last row is a multiple of the outer normal, and since the $d$-th entry is the same, it is equal to the outer normal.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It's painfully easy now I see it (as usual…).

Comment: I just realized that there is a little regularity problem with this proof if you only have $\mathcal{C}^1$ boundary, since then you only know that $\phi$ is continuous, not necessarily differentiable. You might have to assume $\mathcal{C}^2$ boundary for it to work.

Comment: But wouldn't the Gauss map be as differentiable as the manifold? Globally only if it's orientable of course, but locally at least?

Comment: The Gauss map in coordinates involves first partial derivatives, so if the surface is $\mathcal{C}^k$, its Gauss map should be $\mathcal{C}^{k-1}$.

Comment: Ok. I'll just stick with $C^2$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have question, why in the last matrix, the right down entry is phi(x’) not -phi(x’). I was thinking that you take derivative with respect to gamma(x’). It should give you -Id?

Comment: Sorry, I took the wrong derivative.